# 多次元配列である特定の要素を基準として、その上下左右に値を入れたい

Tags: python, python3

##### 質問事項

下記のような**期待するデータ**にするにはどのような処理を組めば実現できますでしょうか？

```
# 対象データ
test_list = [
    ['.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '#', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.']
]


# 期待するデータ
test_list = [
    ['.', '#', '.'],
    ['#', '#', '#'],
    ['.', '#', '.']
]
```

##### 試した処理

以下に自分が試した処理を記載します。
ただ、これでは一部期待する値が代入されてないのと、余分なところに値が代入されてしまいます。

現段階では解決策が見つからなく、もしお分かりの方がいましたらご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

```
# 対象データ
test_list = [
    ['.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '#', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.']
]

for i in range(len(test_list)):
    for j in range(len(test_list)):
        try:
            if test_list[i][j+1] == '#' or test_list[i][j-1] == '#' or test_list[i-1][j] == '#' or test_list[i+1][j] == '#':
                test_list[i][j] = '#'
        except IndexError:
            pass
print(test_list[0])
print(test_list[1])
print(test_list[2])

# 出力結果
['.', '#', '.']
['#', '#', '.']
['#', '#', '.']
```

Answer (score 1):

scipyの`binary_dilation()`を使うと簡単です。
[scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation — SciPy Manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation.html)

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import binary_dilation

def set_closs(lst, s):
    arr = np.array(lst)
    arr[binary_dilation(arr == s)] = s
    return arr.tolist()
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。こんな素晴らしいライブラリーがあるんですね。こちらも、ぜひ使わせていただきます。

Answer (score 0):

複数`#`が存在する可能性も考え下記のようなコードではどうでしょうか？

```
test_list = [
    ['.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '#', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.']
]

indexes = []
for i in range(len(test_list)):
    for j in range(len(test_list[0])):
        if test_list[i][j] == "#":
            indexes.append((i-1,j))
            indexes.append((i,j-1))
            indexes.append((i,j+1))
            indexes.append((i+1,j))
            
for (i, j) in indexes:
    try:
        test_list[i][j] = "#"
    except IndexError:
        pass
print(test_list)
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
なるほど。この発想はありませんでした。
確かに、複数ある場合もあるので、これはすごく参考になります。

Answer (score 0):

numpy を使っても良いのであれば

```
def set_closs(lst, s):
    import numpy as np
    ary = np.array(lst)
    for idx in zip(*np.where(ary==s)):
        ary[max(0,idx[0]-1):idx[0]+2, idx[1]] = ary[idx]
        ary[idx[0], max(0,idx[1]-1):idx[1]+2] = ary[idx]
    return ary.tolist()

# 対象データ
test_list = [
    ['.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '#', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.']
]

out_list = set_closs(test_list, '#')
print(*out_list, sep='\n')
"""
['.', '#', '.']
['#', '#', '#']
['.', '#', '.']
"""

test_list = [
    ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '#', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '#', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.']
]
out_list = set_closs(test_list, '#')
print(*out_list, sep='\n')
"""
['.', '#', '.', '.']
['#', '#', '#', '.']
['.', '#', '#', '#']
['.', '.', '#', '.']
"""
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
numpyでも問題ありません。こちらもとても参考になります。
ありがとうございます。